# Find overlapping edges on a graph

Tags: javascript, overlap

I have edges on a graph that are described as points (x, y).

An example graph with two overlaps:

[image]

This graph has 4 edges described as points:

1. A -> B:

```
const edgeAB = [
  { x: 375, y: 130 },
  { x: 375, y: 160 },
  { x: 165, y: 160 },
  { x: 165, y: 230 },
];
```

2. A -> C:

```
const edgeAC = [
  { x: 375, y: 130 },
  { x: 375, y: 160 },
  { x: 585, y: 160 },
  { x: 585, y: 230 },
];
```

3. C -> B

```
const edgeCB = [
  { x: 585, y: 330 },
  { x: 585, y: 360 },
  { x: 350, y: 360 },
  { x: 350, y: 280 },
  { x: 300, y: 280 },
];
```

4. B -> C

```
const edgeBC = [
  { x: 165, y: 330 },
  { x: 165, y: 360 },
  { x: 400, y: 360 },
  { x: 400, y: 280 },
  { x: 450, y: 280 },
];
```

Giving that information, how to find the overlappings? It would be best to know where the overlapping starts and ends, and what edges it involves.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with finding every horizontal/vertical line which creates the edge.

For example:

```
const lines = {
    "AB": [
        { x1: 375, y1: 130, x2: 375, y2: 160 },
        { x1: 165, y1: 160, x2: 165, y2: 230 },
    ],
    // rest of edges
}
```

Then for every line of the edge I would check every line from other edges. (example - check AB line with other)

```
const lineAB = { x1: 375, y1: 130, x2: 375, y2: 160 };
const compareLine = { x1: 375, y1: 130, x2: 375, y2: 160 }; // in this example its AC edge line

const isLineABVertical = lineAB.x1 === lineAB.x2;
const isCompareLineVertical = compareLine.x1 === compareLine.x2;

if(isLineABVertical !== isCompareLineVertical) {
    // two lines can't overlap - both have different directions
    return;
}
```

And then you need to check **x** for horizontal, **y** for vertical if they overlap.

```
if(isLineABVertical) {
    // vertical - check y

    const { y1, y2 } = lineAB;
    const { y1: cy1, y2: cy2 } = compareLine;

    const isOverlap = y1 <= cy2 && cy1 <= y2;
    if(!isOverlap)
        return;

    // lines are overlapping, push it to the array or sth
} else {
    // horizontal - check x
}
```